# Distribute apps using iCloud

Tags: ios5, icloud

Is it possible to distribute enterprise apps using iCloud as the download location?

I want to be able for a user to use a common username and password to connect to the
iCloud and be able to download the enterprise app and install it.

thank you

tony

Answer (score 0):

You could, however remember that you would need to remain signed in with that iCloud account to sync with that accounts iCloud store. I don't think it would be practical unless all devices having the same account is ok.